# How to display a web page in java web application containing Google Calendar of another user (who had authorized me to do so previously)

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google API v3 and OAuth 2 authorization. Another user had authorized me to view/write events in his agenda. From my Java web application, how should I start to make his Google Calendar Agenda appears on his screen after I submit an action from a button? I can get events, write events but not in 'Google Agenda web page' format. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by Google Agenda web page? Is it the window that pops up when a meeting reminder is shown?

Comment: No, it's not... it's pretty much similar to this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552297/how-to-display-in-another-web-page-google-agenda-from-someone-else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552297/how-to-display-in-another-web-page-google-agenda-from-someone-else)